# Which is the case for permission?

Tags: linux, permissions

```
-rwx-
 124 
 421
```

Which is right??

I'm confused .

Anyone knows this?

Comment: @jw013 has given you the correct answer, but for your future reference, this is available to you in your systems documentation - `man chmod` in this case explains the file mode bits in detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
rwx
421
```

Read it like a binary number (place values increase to the left)